# HTML email looks different in Yahoo, Hotmail and Gmail

Tags: html, css

I am sending HTML email, but my email looks different on different email clients e.g **Yahoo**, **Hotmail** and **Gmail**. I have used `<style>` tag to use media queries for mobile device then Yahoo and Hotmail using that style sheet.

Comment: Do you have ANY code to show us or must we guess?

Comment: Welcome to html email design!

Answer (score 2):

Email clients all handle CSS differently - they support different properties and sometimes explicitly don't allow some. It's a lot harder than styling for web browsers.

Here are some resources for creating email designs:

[Guide to using CSS in HTML emails](http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/)

[Table of CSS support in different email clients](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) (from @donald123's answer)

[HTML email template builder](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/templates/) (from @cassi.lup's answer)

[Guide to optimising CSS in emails for mobile devices](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/18/from-monitor-to-mobile-optimizing-email-newsletters-with-css/)

[Mailchimps email templates](http://mailchimp.com/resources/html-email-templates/) (from @cassi.lup's answer)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, that CSS for html emails have to be simple, not all clients understand all css styles :-(

Eg useing tables for layout is in html email a good id ...

Try to search in google for the best way to script your html email. An short overview about the understanding of css styles in major clients can you find here

[understanding of css styles in major clients can you find here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. Start with a correctly formatted template and work your design from there.
   A very helpful resource in this matter is [this service](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/templates/). But keep in mind that you are very limited in terms of CSS tricks.
2. Construct your html-formatted email from images. Then you are sure to have consistency over all browsers, as the design elements you're using will be interpreted similarly.

Another useful resource: http://mailchimp.com/resources/html-email-templates/

Comment: +1 Also some very useful links. I've copied these into my answer I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Well, thanks for the +1. However, the idea was that the person who asked the question would look at all the answers and decide which helped most.

Comment: People ask a question, which tends to end up having one canonical answer. Then when people search for the solution to that question, they can just read that answer. That's why other users can edit answers. The answer isn't owned by the poster, it's public domain on stackoverflow. I agree me stealing your resource is not a good model for correctly attributing credit (which is why I gave you a +1) but that's not what stackoverflow is mainly about. In fact, since I answered first, if you agreed with my answer I could say you should have just collaborated on that one answer rather than compete.

Comment: See here about when to edit posts: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit (including "to add related resources or hyperlinks")

Answer (score 0):

You can get a better idea about the email styles from this [site](http://www.benchmarkemail.com/help-FAQ/answer/Common-HTML-Email-Coding-Mistakes)

Answer (score 0):

personaly i always create a html fiel without a doctype.
then just opening and closing tags for html, head and body.
Then just use tables and only use inline stylesheets.
Also don't forget to remove the table borders, cellpadding and margins because they can, n my experiance, be a big pain.

To fill up space use tabel cells and don't use paddings or margins because the some email clients ignores these.

AND most important of all! Don't use backgrounds.
Try not to use to many images.
Use them for headers, footers or e.g. product images.

Hope it helps and sorry for the grammer ;)